# Java - how to use a value from a class property when calling a constructor

Tags: java, parameters, constructor, arguments, instantiation

I have the following problem:

1. Build the classes `Animal`, `Cat`, and `Bug`.
2. Define the properties `color` and `leg_number` on the
   relevant and necessary classes. Have them be initialized
   within a constructor.
3. Add the functionality that would allow us to call a method
   `move` with the `Cat` and `Bug` classes. Have the method return
   a string "I'm moving with `leg_number` legs!", with the
   "`leg_number`" being `leg_number` as set on the class.
4. Add a new class called `Bird`. Add the property
   `wing_number`. Add the functionality that would allow us to
   call a method `move` with the `Bird` class. Have the method
   return the string "I'm moving with `leg_number` legs!"
   if `wing_number` doesn't have an applicable value. If
   `wing_number` does have an applicable value, return the
   string "I'm flying".

My code thus far is as follows:

```
class Animal {

    protected String color;
    protected int leg_number;

    public Animal(String color, int leg_number) {
        this.color = color;
        this.leg_number = leg_number;
    }

    public void move() {
        System.out.println("I'm moving with " + leg_number + " legs!");
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    String color;
    int leg_number;

    public Cat(String color, int leg_number) {
        super(color, leg_number);
        this.color = "orange";
        this.leg_number = 4;
    }

    @Override
    public void move() {
        System.out.println("I'm moving with " + leg_number + " legs!");
    }
}

class Bug extends Animal {
    String color;
    int leg_number;

    public Bug(String color, int leg_number) {
        super(color, leg_number);
        this.color = "green";
        this.leg_number = 16;
    }

    @Override
    public void move() {
        System.out.println("I'm moving with " + leg_number + " legs!");
    }
}

class Bird extends Animal {
    String color;
    int leg_number;
    int wing_number;

    public Bird(String color, int leg_number, int wing_number) {
        super(color, leg_number);
        this.color = "yellow";
        this.leg_number = 2;
        this.wing_number = wing_number;
    }

    public void move(int wing_number) {
        if (wing_number > 0) {
            System.out.println("I'm flying");
        } else {
            System.out.println("I'm moving with " + leg_number + " legs!");
        }
    }
}
```

I think I did what the instructions called for in setting the value for leg_number in the constructor. I'm not sure how to use it in the constructor call, though. It seems that if I have `Animal myCat = new Cat("orange", 4);` that I'm not following the instructions for the assignment. But I'm not sure what else to put there. I've tried using `(color, leg_number)` and `(this.color, this.leg_number)`, but as expected, they didn't work (I assume because the object hasn't been instantiated yet). I tried setting the values in the parameter list of the constructor itself, but that didn't work either. I tried having the constuctor take no parameters, but I have to call the `super` constructor which does require parameters, so I get an error that way.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: Where I'm trying to instantiate these is in the Main method.

Comment: Don't repost questions. Just [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69713205/edit) the original.

Comment: That question was deleted.

Comment: It shouldn't have been.

Comment: Why do you repeat the color and leg_number in the child classes? They are already declared in Animal.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `String color` and `int leg_number` in your sub-classes. You also don't need to override `move()` method in all sub-classes, except `Bird`. Additionally, your `move()` method in `Bird` shouldn't take any parameters but use `wing_number` property instead. Having said that, try the following:

```java
class Animal {

    protected String color;
    protected int leg_number;

    public Animal(String color, int leg_number) {
        this.color = color;
        this.leg_number = leg_number;
    }

    public void move() {
        System.out.println("I'm moving with " + leg_number + " legs!");
    }
}
```

```java
class Cat extends Animal {
    public Cat(String color, int leg_number) {
        super(color, leg_number);
    }
}
```

```java
class Bug extends Animal {
    public Bug(String color, int leg_number) {
        super(color, leg_number);
    }
}
```

```java
class Bird extends Animal {
    private int wing_number;

    public Bird(String color, int leg_number, int wing_number) {
        super(color, leg_number);
        this.wing_number = wing_number;
    }

    @Override
    public void move() {
        if (wing_number > 0) {
            System.out.println("I'm flying");
        } else {
            super.move();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that I need to set the values in the class, not as arguments when calling the constructor.

Comment: You clearly wrote "Have them be initialized within a constructor.". What do you mean by "I need to set the values in the class, not as arguments when calling the constructor."?